# Trying to space 2 divs between each other at the bottom

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to make the following happen:

- On image hover, at the bottom it will show comments/reactions on the left and name on the right

I cannot get the 2 divs to space between at the bottom and I do not know why.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/jyBq62Ok90 is the working code

Comment: What you want , can you elaborate?

Comment: Is this what you want to archive https://play.tailwindcss.com/SazptwT0A9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a width, e.g. `w-full` on the absolute positioned div. Otherwise the div will be as wide as the content and there will be no space between.

[See this tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/zLFvBjg40q)

Hope this helps.

Comment: See and I thought that too but the content overflows at the bottom so I abandoned that. I think I need to revisit why it overflows to correct that. Thank you for the solution

Comment: What do you mean by the overflow? That the buttons scale with the image? Is this what you need: https://play.tailwindcss.com/TKHcZJr6E7

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood , you need to highlight the comment div below as you hover the image with a space between two divs

You can use `group-hover` utility with a div wrapper. Below code will help you much more

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="group">
  <div class="group mb-4 flex aspect-auto w-full overflow-visible duration-300 ease-in hover:scale-105 hover:rounded-lg">
    <img src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F13%2F2015%2F04%2F05%2Ffeatured.jpg&q=60" class="h-full w-full bg-gray-900 object-cover hover:opacity-40" />
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-0 mx-4 mb-4 hidden bg-gray-700 px-3 duration-300 group-hover:block group-hover:transition group-hover:ease-in">
    <div class="flex justify-between">
      <div class="flex text-sm font-medium text-white">
        <ChatAlt2Icon class="h-5 w-5 text-white" />
        <span class="pl-1 text-white">12</span>
        <HeartIcon class="ml-2 h-5 w-5 text-white" />
        <span class="pl-1 text-white">12</span>
      </div>
      <div class="flex text-white">Added: Today</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```